# Force systemd's mount and automount to raise inmediately ENOENT instead ENODEV

Tags: systemd, mount, nfs, nas

I have an external drive which provides an NFS mounting point, and I want to use it as a NAS.

I would like to be mounted when I try to access it. I've done it with Systemd's units file, with a .mount and .automount units placed on `/etc/systemd/system/`. It is working correctly when the storage device is on.

But when it is turned off and I want to access it, it takes ages to resolve an stat system call (like doing an `ls`, for example) and it returns a `ENODEV`. Instead, I would like to return instantly a `ENOENT` status code, as if the file does not exist at all.

Both units are enabled and running.

File: `mnt-NAS.mount`

```
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service
  Wants=network-online.target

[Mount]
  What=192.168.1.252:/mnt/md1
  Where=/mnt/NAS
  Options=rw,hard,intr,wsize=8192,nofail
  Type=nfs
  TimeoutSec=1

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

File: `mnt-NAS.mount`

```
[Unit]
  Description=nfs mount script
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Automount]
  Where=/mnt/NAS
  TimeoutIdleSec=30

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It could be a Systemd's option I am missing?